# How to determine that NFC is disabled in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, nfc

I've seen in many articles a way to check that NFC is disabled like this:

```
if (ProximityDevice.GetDefault() != null)
   MessageBox.Show("NFC present");
else
   MessageBox.Show("Your phone has no NFC or NFC is disabled");
```

`ProximityDevice.GetDefault()` is indeed returning `null` if a phone has no NFC module.

But when I check it on a phone that has NFC module that I've turned off in Settings `ProximityDevice.GetDefault()` returns a normal ProximityDevice like if NFC is enabled.

Is there any working way to determine that NFC is turned off?

Comment: I think there is no way to check whether it is on or not but instead you can check with above code that it is available or not in Device, If Available then you can Initialize its object and publish the data if You got Proximate device id arrived. see this link, you would have idea about it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/br241212.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, `ProximityDevice.GetDefault()` will not tell if the phone has NFC hardware or not.

`ProximityDevice.GetDeviceSelector()` is also useless as it reports the same 'device' despite being run on a Lumia 520 (does not have NFC) and a Lumia 1520 (does have NFC).

There are a few options...

1. If your app uses NFC as an additional feature, you can tell the user "NFC disable or unavailable", not ideal but that's all you can do in this situation.
2. If your app's primary features reply on NFC, [then use the 'hardware requirements' part of the App Manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206936(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_Hardwarerequirements) to exclude devices that don't have NFC - a user without NFC hardware on their phone will **not** be able to download your app from the Windows Phone Store.
3. In future if you're targeting Windows Phone 8.1 (Silverlight or WinRT), [there is a newer API called DeviceInformation which may help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.enumeration.deviceinformation.properties.aspx).

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. I have a Lumia 1520 and I am running a Windows 8.1 app to detect the phone.

Comment: @ScottNimrod have you used the newer WinRT APIs in 8.1?

Comment: @ScottNimrod I'm sorry, but this question relates specifically to Windows Phone 8.

Comment: I was trying to establish an NFC between my Windows Phone 8 and my Surface Pro. I was building a WP8 app. I believe both devices must be supported.

Comment: @ScottNimrod yes, two devices or a device + NFC enabled card

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Windows.Devices.Enumeration APIs for this one, but the trick is that ProximityDevice.GetDeviceSelector() has a clause in it that restricts the query to only enabled devices so you need to remove that clause.

So the code you'll need is below, note that big ugly string with the GUID in it came from ProximityDevice.GetDeviceSelector() just with one of the clauses removed:

```
var proximityDevices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync("System.Devices.InterfaceClassGuid:=\"{FB3842CD-9E2A-4F83-8FCC-4B0761139AE9}\"");
if (proximityDevices.Count > 0)
{
    // NFC proximity IS supported on this device
    if(proximityDevices[0].IsEnabled)
    {
        // NFC proximity has not been disabled in the control panel
    }
    else
    {
        // NFC proximity has been disabled by the user in the control panel
    }
}
else
{
    // NFC proximity is NOT supported on this device
}
```